# Maven plugin loading classes

Tags: class, maven, classloader, maven-plugin, maven-3

I have an application which has legacy Struts actions extending org.apache.struts.StrutsActions. I would like to be sure that all my classes which are extending StrutsActions have a custom annotation.

In order to provide this I have written a small maven enforcer rule to validate my requirement. However I dont know how to load my classes at my mojo to validate them.

Actually I have done something not fancy which is injection outputDirectory and with a custom class loader I have recursively loaded all classes at my build folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with the help of [reflections](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/)

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
     <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
     <version>0.9.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

my implementation is like this:

```
public void execute(EnforcerRuleHelper helper) throws EnforcerRuleException {

    URL url = getURL(helper.evaluate("${project.build.outputDirectory}"));

    Predicate<String> filter = new FilterBuilder().include(getTargetSuperTypeForSubtypes());
    Predicate<String> filter2 = new FilterBuilder().include(getMustHaveAnnotation());

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .setScanners(
        new TypeAnnotationsScanner().filterResultsBy(filter2),
        new SubTypesScanner().filterResultsBy(filter))
     .setUrls(url));

    validate(reflections);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All classes ? What do you mean by that ?  Maybe you mean target/classes/**  (which is the default output place for classes)  or maybe you mean a list of multiple directory tree locations ?

Can you better explain what your Mojo does and which phase and goals you want it to bind with.

I think maybe you are thinking about how to apply Maven's build cycle to your project incorrectly.  Could you explain better what your plugin does, maybe it is does "packaging" work ?

But if I understand you correctly you want the plugin's execution to pickup the additional classpath entry for target/classes/** ?   So it can load code and resources from the project itself to change some dynamic behaviour inside the maven-plugin ?

The default way to do this is `<dependency>` however of course this requires a fixed unit.

Other plugins that allow for this behavior (like maven-antrun-plugin) provide a mechansism to change classpath inside the Mojo and use something from `<configuration>` section of their pom.xml to do it.  It is not clear if the plugin you are using is a Maven one or one you have written ?

.

Validation and packaging that is a valid use case.  But I question why on the "classpath" ?  I would guess you are binding on process-classes phase.

i.e. the classpath is for the purpose of providing code/resources to the runtime to execute.  But in your case you have an input directory rather than a class path requirement.

It is possible in a Mojo to setup a directory scanner on an input directory **/*.class and then it is possible to (using some library) open each file and inspect the annotation without loading it.

This is also a good kind of separation between unreliable input data and the consistent behaviour of the plugin code itself.  What happens if a project decides it wants to implement the same package and/or class as used in the implementation of the plugin itself.

UPDATE: If you really are loading the classes you are checkig into the JVM from your Mojo, then at least implement your own ClassLoader to do it.  This is not necessarily a simple problem to solve.  You make this ClassLoader find things specified from configuration in the input directory.